# Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list on line 1

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, soundcloud

I have some problems with my code. I get the error:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list

The error also says the mistake is on line 1 o the following code:

```
<?php 
include ("../useractions/checkuser.php"); 
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>test</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <!--<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black">
    <meta name="mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes"> -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../styles/musicstyle.css">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="../images/bzapplogo.ico">
    <link href="../images/bzapplogo.png" rel="apple-touch-icon" />
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://connect.soundcloud.com/sdk.js"></script>
    <script src="play.js"></script>
    <script> 
        // Menü-Button zum ein und ausfahren vom Menü
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#hammenu").click(function(){
            $("#navmenu").slideToggle("fast");
            });
        });
    </script>
    <script src="../javascripts/links.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="section">  
        <div id="headerbar">
            <div id="hammenu">
                <div id="firstmenu"></div>
                <div id="secondmenu"></div>
                <div id="thirdmenu"></div>
            </div>
            <div id="navmenu">
                <ul>
                    <li onclick="sortasc()">Alphabet</li>
                    <li onclick="sortrating()">Rating</li>
                    <li onclick="sortlatest()">Latest</li>
                    <li onclick="sorttrending()">Trending</li>
                    <li onclick="sortrecommended()">Recommended</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script>
            $( document ).ready(function() {
                $("#content").load("sorts/rating.php");
            });

            function sortasc() {
                $("#content").load("sorts/asc.php");
                $("#navmenu").slideToggle("slow");
            }

            function sortrating() {
                $("#content").load("sorts/rating.php");
                $("#navmenu").slideToggle("slow");
            }

            function sortlatest() {
                 $("#content").load("sorts/latest.php");
                  $("#navmenu").slideToggle("slow");
            }

            function sorttrending() {
                 $("#content").load("sorts/trending.php");
                 $("#navmenu").slideToggle("slow");
            } 

            function sortrecommended() {
                 $("#content").load("sorts/recommended.php");
                  $("#navmenu").slideToggle("slow");
            }
        </script>
        <div id="content">   

        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="footer">
        <input type="button" href="#" id="playbutton" class="button" value="" onclick="playTrackFast()" disabled/>
        <input type="button" href="#" id="pausebutton" class="button" value="" onclick="pauseTrack()" style="display:none; background:url(../images/pausebutton.png) no-repeat background-size: 50px 50px;" disabled/>
        <p id="footerSongtitel" style="">Songtitel</p>
    </div>
</body>
```

Maybe the problem is in the javascript-file:

```
SC.initialize({
client_id: "myclientid"
});

var playing = false;
var soundToPlay;
var TrackLink;
function StreamStart(NewID) {
    TrackLink = "/tracks/" + NewID;
    SC.stream(TrackLink, {
        useHTML5Audio: true,
        preferFlash: false,
        onfinish: function(){
            var elems = $(".songdiv");
            if (elems.length){
                var keep = Math.floor(Math.random() * elems.length);
                console.log(keep);
                $(elems[keep]).click();
            }
            },
         whileplaying: function () {
        console.log(this.position);
        }

    }, function(sound) {
    if (playing){
        soundToPlay.destruct();
        document.getElementById('playbutton').style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById('pausebutton').style.display = 'inline-block';
    } else {
    soundToPlay = sound;
    document.getElementById('playbutton').disabled = false;
    document.getElementById('pausebutton').disabled = false;
    document.getElementById('stopbutton').disabled = false;
    document.getElementById('playbutton').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('pausebutton').style.display = 'inline-block';
    playing = true;
    }
});
}

function playTrack() {
    setTimeout("soundToPlay.play()", 1500);
}

function playTrackFast() {
soundToPlay.play();
document.getElementById('playbutton').style.display = 'none';
document.getElementById('pausebutton').style.display = 'inline-block';
}

function pauseTrack() {
soundToPlay.pause();
document.getElementById('playbutton').style.display = 'inline-block';
document.getElementById('pausebutton').style.display = 'none';
}

function stopTrack() {
  soundToPlay.destruct();
}


function changeSongtitle(songtitle) {
$('#footerSongtitel').innerHMTL = songtitle;
}
```

I read that the problem often is because of jQuery... Could this be my problem?

FYI - It's a soundcloud-player(Stream)

Thanks

Comment: <?php 
session_start (); 
if (!isset ($_SESSION["user_id"])) 
{ 
    header ("Location: http://domain.ch/useractions/formular.php"); 
} 
?>

Comment: Which browser did you run with ? Try Chrome Console error logger and click the link to switch to line of error.

Comment: I'm using chrome. The link switches to the Doctype...

Comment: Please show error description which chrome specify with Red Underline after you've clicked the Console error  link .

Comment: The file with the error should be shown next to the error in the console. No need to guess at the file. Also, Line 1 is often reported when the script is minimised as the whole script is on a single line...

Comment: sortsongasc.php line 1       this is the file from the code above.

Answer (score 1):

**I was getting this error even though my javascript code was perfectly fine.**

The problem was someone else. My Database password was incorrect which was throwing some hidden errors and because of which this error was popuing up in the browser. Fixing DB password, fixed this error automatically. Hope this helps somebody.

Answer (score 0):

I found the mistake: One variable gives the songtitle to the JS-file. Now one Songtitle contained brackets. So the title-bracket closed a function of the js file...

Thanks to everyone for their help!

Answer (score -1):

include ("../useractions/checkuser.php");  Use absolute path instead relative path in include function

Comment: How is this in any way an answer to the question?